# How to get the value of a <button>?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to run a certain part of my PHP code (which is within the same page as my HTML) when a certain button is clicked. We use if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit]) in PHP for an html button that is , but I can't seem to figure out the PHP counterpart for executing code when a `<button>` is clicked. I have to use `<button>`, not `<input>`, which I've figured out.

Comment: Oh boy. oh boy. Add some of your code?

Comment: Paste the HTML part of the button

Comment: @HawasKaPujaari

I think it's fairly clear from the question that the OP doesn't know.. Hence the simple and self explanitory question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same way in both cases and does *not change* between `<input type=submit>` and [`<button type=submit>`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-button-element) elements.

Make sure the button-button has a name, is given the submit action,  is enabled, is inside the form, and was pressed to initiate the post-back.

Access it by name, and optionally check the value if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a solution like this (because it's in the same page) :

```
<form method='POST' action='<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>'>
     <input type="submit" value="submit" name="blablabla" />
</form>
```

and :

```
if(isset($_POST['blablabla']){
   //execution
}
```

Comment: will you check with `value` or `name`??

Comment: Welcome on Stack Overflow. You forgot `name=""` in your `input` and the question is about a `<button>`, suggesting `<input />` is off-topic.

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, you're right, it's name="blablabla" what I'd like to say :)